# Functional component is rerendered more than should

Tags: reactjs

In the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often) I have found this component that is supposed to be rendered only twice:

```
function Users() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  console.log("---: " + count)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect")

    const id = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("setCount: " + (count + 1))
      setCount(count + 1); // This effect depends on the `count` state
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(id);

  }, []); //  Bug: `count` is not specified as a dependency

  return <h1>{count}</h1>;
}
```

Try running previous component and you will get [this logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwBv9.png) where it is visible that a component is rerendered three times. So one unnecessary render happens (only one but still), even though **setState** has returned the same value. Can someone explain this, please?

Comment: It will render infinite times because of setInterval. Its not only three time . See it in your console its already 864 times rendered

Comment: No. SetInterval was called 864 times, but rerender happened only three times. "setCount" is logged on setInterval, and "---: " is logged on component render.